# Swatches in list on product view

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, product-list, product-view, swatches

Using the new configurable swatches from Magento CE 1.9.1 I would like to show swatches in product view for the "main" product, but also for a list of products.

I am able to get the swatches in view, but only the swatches on the main product are functional (image changing)

Comment: you need to show swatches in product list ?

Comment: More or less. On the product view page, i have a 2 lists containing other products. I want the swatches on that list as well